# Error in downloading IcedTea web Start

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, environment-variables, icedtea

I executed the command:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

...and this error was displayed:

```
Error in downloading IcedTea web Start..
```

A screenshot of the terminal session:

[image: error that is displayed]

Please Help!

Comment: sorry we can't see your error..

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/environment`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that only one line is present in `/etc/environment` file.

Open the file `/etc/environment` in an editor

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

And check the double quote at the end of the line. Compare the content with the line below, note the double quote at end of the line.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```